# Favicon 404 Error even though rel='icon' is set

Tags: html, favicon

I am getting this intermittent error for some visitors to my site where even though I've specified a favicon in this format:

```
<link type="image/png" href="icon.png" rel="icon" />
```

Some users are still getting a 404 error for favicon.ico as if some browser by default is looking for that filename.  I'm having a lot of trouble tracking down how this could be happening as I've never used anything called favicon.ico.  Anyone have an idea?  Thanks.

Comment: Some browsers look for `favicon.ico` no matter what you do.

Comment: @thirtydot why?

Comment: @Ooker: Sometimes there's a `favicon.ico` file, but no reference to it in the HTML. Browsers *really* like to display the icon, so they check for one in the default path. It's a very old behaviour.

Comment: @thirtydot why do they really like to display the icon, to the point that if there is no `favicon.ico` in the default path, then other methods don't work?

Comment: @Ooker: Other methods do work just fine. I see from your recent questions that you've been having some troubles with favicons. You're either doing something slightly wrong, or running into a browser bug. Try clearing your cache or with a different browser. This isn't the place for this discussion.

Comment: @thirtydot no I've worked out my problem. I just wonder why "some browsers look for favicon.ico no matter what you do". Because that implies that "if there is no favicon.ico in the default path, then other methods don't work"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put an a ".ico" file in the root directory and name it favicon.ico so that all browsers will understand the favourite icon.

Comment: He shouldn't have to name it favicon if he links to it, but it's still a good idea anyway, and don't most modern browsers recognize both .ico and .png favicons? I thought they do, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I didn't tried to use the .png because i think it is a standard for all browser that when the browser find a file named favicon.ico, it displays it without the need of adding any code.

Answer (score 1):

I think IE6 doesn't support PNG images as favicons, so it's possible it's trying to download favicon.ico instead. Also, the [Wikipedia article on favicons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) suggests there are more IE-related problems. See the *Browser implementation* tables.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the problem could be without seeing the site. Would you mind posting a link to it here?

Also, are you sure that 'icon.png' exists in the same directory as your page, and is viewable through the browser?